# Capturing frames from Gstreamer opencv and glade

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, glade

i am trying to get gstreamer to capture frames and have them put into a picture box on a glade form ,  this is my Code snippet so far ,   can anyone give me come guidance

```
  GstCaps *caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
        // Get a string containg the pixel format, width and height of the image        
        str = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);    

        if( strcmp( gst_structure_get_string (str, "format"),"BGRx") == 0)  
        {
            // Now query the width and height of the image
            gst_structure_get_int (str, "width", &width);
            gst_structure_get_int (str, "height", &height);

            // Create a cv::Mat, copy image data into that and save the image.
            d->OpenCVImage.create(height,width,CV_8UC(4));
            memcpy( d->OpenCVImage.data, info.data, width*height*4);
        }
    }

    // Calling Unref is important!
    gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &info);
    gst_sample_unref(sample);

#endif
    d->bImageReceived = true; 
    d->pImageEvent->set(); // Set the event, so the image will be processed
}
return GST_FLOW_OK;
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: so i don't know how much more clear i need to be , i have written a GUI in Glade it has a picture control on it. and i am using a camera from the imaging source i need to use gstreamer i need frames from the camera translate into Images to show up in the picture box so i can use open-CV to Edge detect